# SoundCloud Stream in Phonegap under Android

Tags: android, audio, cordova, soundcloud

I'm currently trying to get the SoundCloud API working under PhoneGap/Cordova and Android. Here's the code that is working fine within the browser:

```
  var track_url = 'http://soundcloud.com/mymusic/mymusic'
    ;
    SC.get('/resolve', {
        url : track_url
    }, function(track) {

        $("#stream").live("click", function() {
            SC.stream("/tracks/" + track.id, function(sound) {
                sound.play();
                $("#stop").live("click", function() {
                    sound.stop();
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

On my android debug device however there is no sound. LogCat doesn't give any standard or cordova errors. Has anyone encountered this before?

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks okay and I was able to test it successfully on Android. The only thing I can think of is that the resolve call is returning a 404 or similar. Have you tried checking for an error?

```
var track_url = 'http://soundcloud.com/your/track';

SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
});

SC.get('/resolve', { url: track_url }, function(track, error) {
  if (error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.message);
    return;
  }

  // ... rest of your code
});
```

Try that and see if you get anything, if not, leave a comment.

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks for the help. I included your error alert into the code. The SC.get is not throwing any error and it gives me the same valid track.id like in the browser. I narrowed it down to the SC.stream that is completely inactive under android/PG. It simply skips this part without error or catch. But my Galaxy S2 (ICS) gives me a chromium error:     `D/chromium(28352): Unknown chromium error: -6`

Comment: Update: I also tried the emulator on older OS-versions. I don't get the chromium error there but the alerts within the `SC.stream` don't fire either.